# Finding the distance between two nodes for TranslateTransition

Tags: java, animation, javafx, translate-animation

In my program, I want objects to appear that they are moving from one spot to another. I used the `TranslateTransition`. For it to work, I need to give it a starting location, in my case, the distance to the starting node.

[image]

The problem, is the two nodes are in separate containers, so simply using `layoutX` and `layoutY` in the calculation will not work.

In my code below, I used the `localToScene` method for converting coordinates relative to the local node to the scene. Then I did a little subtraction to get the distance between the two nodes relative to the moving node.

```
import com.neonorb.commons.log.Log;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.Observable;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.DoubleBinding;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.LazyReflectiveObjectGenerator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Created by chris on 8/23/15.
 */
public class TranslateUtils {
    public static DoubleProperty getTranslateX(Node translatingNode, Node otherNode) {
        DoubleProperty ret = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            List<Observable> dependencies = getAllParents(translatingNode).stream().map(Node::layoutXProperty).collect(Collectors.toList());
            dependencies.addAll(getAllParents(otherNode).stream().map(Node::layoutXProperty).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            ret.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(new Callable<Double>() {
                @Override
                public Double call() throws Exception {
                    Log.debug("recalculating x");
                    return otherNode.localToScene(otherNode.getBoundsInLocal()).getMinX() - translatingNode.localToScene(translatingNode.getBoundsInLocal()).getMinX();
                }
            }, dependencies.toArray(new Observable[dependencies.size()])));
        });
        return ret;
    }

    public static DoubleProperty getTranslateY(Node translatingNode, Node otherNode) {
        DoubleProperty ret = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            List<Observable> dependencies = getAllParents(translatingNode).stream().map(Node::layoutXProperty).collect(Collectors.toList());
            dependencies.addAll(getAllParents(otherNode).stream().map(Node::layoutXProperty).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            ret.bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(new Callable<Double>() {
                @Override
                public Double call() throws Exception {
                    Log.debug("recalculating y");
                    return otherNode.localToScene(otherNode.getBoundsInLocal()).getMinY() - translatingNode.localToScene(translatingNode.getBoundsInLocal()).getMinY();
                }
            }, dependencies.toArray(new Observable[dependencies.size()])));
        });
        return ret;
    }

    private static List<Parent> getAllParents(Node node) {
        List<Parent> parents = new ArrayList<Parent>();
        Parent parent = node.getParent();
        if (parent != null) {
            parents.addAll(getAllParents(parent));
            parents.add(parent);
        }
        return parents;
    }
}
```

You can test the code with this:

```
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import org.controlsfx.tools.Borders;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Created by chris on 7/20/15.
 */
public class Test extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        Label translatingNode = new Label("translating node");
        HBox translatingHBox = new HBox(translatingNode);
        translatingHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        borderPane.setTop(translatingHBox);
        Label referenceNode = new Label("reference node");
        HBox referenceHBox = new HBox(referenceNode);
        referenceHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
        borderPane.setBottom(referenceHBox);
        TranslateTransition translateTransition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(3), translatingNode);
        translateTransition.fromXProperty().bind(TranslateUtils.getTranslateX(translatingNode, referenceNode));
        translateTransition.fromYProperty().bind(TranslateUtils.getTranslateY(translatingNode, referenceNode));
        translateTransition.setToX(0);
        translateTransition.setToY(0);
        Button playButton = new Button("play");
        playButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                translateTransition.play();
            }
        });
        borderPane.setCenter(playButton);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

You can successfully play the animation the first time, but try resizing the window. The translate locations don't get updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using custom methods to find the global location:

```
private static double getGlobalX(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    double parentGlobalX = getGlobalX(node.getParent());
    return node.getLayoutX() - parentGlobalX;
}

private static double getGlobalY(Node node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return 0.0;
    }
    double parentGlobalY = getGlobalY(node.getParent());
    return parentGlobalY - node.getLayoutY();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not including the `layoutXProperty` of the `translatingNode` itself. To fix your demo, just include the Node itself in the list of its parents:

```
private static List<Node> getAllParents(Node node) {
    List<Node> parents = new ArrayList<Node>();
    if (node != null) {
        parents.addAll(getAllParents(node.getParent()));
        parents.add(node);
    }
    return parents;
}
```

Comment: That was an issue but in my case that was not the problem.

Comment: I am using custom methods to find the location instead of the built in ones. This might have fixed the problem, but I doubt it. Not going to test it either :)